# What is the difference between applets loaded over the net and applets loaded via the file system?

Tags: java, applet

I know there are two different ways that applets are loaded by a Java system.

1.Applet loaded over the net.
2.Applet loaded via the file system.

But i dont know what is the difference between those?

Please guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked google the same question and found [this](http://www.tipsoninterview.in/applets-interview-questions), where #17 is the exact same question.

Comment: The exact same phrasing as well :O